# Flutter - AWS S3 image upload using only aws key and secret (Without using any Package/SDK)

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, amazon-s3

I was trying to upload my image to AWS s3 bucket storage. Most of the AWS s3 image upload examples in google are asking to use the lambda function for uploading an image to the server.

But, I do not want to use lambda function.

So is there any way if I can upload my images to my public bucket URL with my AWS "**key**" and "**secret**"?

Can anyone suggest me a way to upload image thoroughly from mobile side only?

Thanks.

Comment: found Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the signing process and use the S3 API endpoint, which is what packages/SDKs are doing under the hood.

The S3 REST API documentation with the supported parameters are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html

And to calculate the signature using the access key id and the secret access key you'll need this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html

The documentation seems decent, but it won't be easy.